# Divergence of Gradient Method

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Is there any example of a continuous differentiable function out there, in which the gradient method with Armijo's stepsize-rule doesn't converge? 
I found it pretty hard to create one myself because the Armijo-Rule isn't that easy to handle with.

I would be glad for some help, Thanks!